# Firebase integration with Slack

Tags: firebase, slack

I've integrated ten projects from firebase with a slack channel where I'm posting crashes notifications. Ater I integrated the 10th app, the 11th integration didn't work and I followed the same procedure.

I can't find anything in the docs related to slack limitations, except that I can only send one message per second. Anyone has any pointers to solve this?

Comment: Are you on a free plan for Slack? Its limited to max 10 integrations / apps.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken Yes, it's free. Do you have any link to the documentation, so that I can check that out?

Comment: see here: https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/115002422943-Message-file-storage-and-app-limits-on-the-Free-plan

Comment: You can also see your limit and current usage in your workspace on the Analytics page for admins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are limited to max. 10 integrations / apps on a free plan Slack. ([source](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/115002422943-Message-file-storage-and-app-limits-on-the-Free-plan))

Upgrading to a paid plan would obviously solve the issue.

There also might be some other workaround depending on the specifics (which currently are unclear).

e.g. if the integrations are based on incomoing webhooks, then its possible to limit the number of integrations by using the same webhook for different channels / providers.